# Disable "dynamic links" in rich text fields

Tags: entries, url, field, redactor, richtext

When we're adding a "link > link to an entry" to a rich text field, this will result in a link to `https://www.site.com/page#entry:3962:url` and we understand what the purpose is of this additional `#entry:3962:url`, but is there a way to disable this?

The multi-domain setup we created is not compatible with this feature, so it will create links that are broken. The easiest fix for our customer is to disable this feature all together. Is that possible and how?

Comment: You can disable the `link` function in your redactor by removing the option... In your backend field settings you'll have a field configuration in your `rich text field` and you can create your own redactor with custom options. So you can copy the options from craft and remove the `link`

Comment: @RobinSchambach Yeah, but we still want the ability to easily add links to entries, just not with the `#entry:3962:url` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and we understand what the purpose is of this additional `#entry:3962:url`, but is there a way to disable this?

Currently not.  You'd need to write a Craft/Redactor plugin that used the [addRichTextLinkOptions](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#addRichTextLinkOptions) hook to do something similar to what the default "Link to an Entry" does, but with your own custom logic.